# biblatex: why no comma after abbreviated shorttitle?

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

Sorry, this is only a minor question, but I just realised for the first time that when you cite a bibliographic item which has no shortitle, then -- using `style=verbose` -- you usually get (apart from the very first `fullcite`):

> Name, *In Physica*, p.12.

When this item has an abbreviated `shorttitle` that ends with a `dot`, however, you get the following:

> Name, *In Phys.* p.12. [No comma after shorttitle/before page!]

I usually omit the "p." for "page", so my result is:

> Name, *In Phys.* 12.

I would like to get:

> Name, *In Phys.*, 12.

### MWE

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, DIV=calc]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}    
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[    style=verbose,
            abbreviate=false,
            url=false,
            backrefstyle=three,
            backend=biber
                ]{biblatex}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}       % postnotes without p. and pp.

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{without:shorttitle,
    author = {Author W. Name},
    year = {2000},
    title = {In Physica},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    }
@book{with:shorttitle,
    author = {Author W. Name},
    year = {2000},
    title = {In Physica},
    shorttitle = {In Phys.},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

''First citation without shorttitle.''\footcite[12]{without:shorttitle}

''Second citation without shorttitle.''\footcite[12]{without:shorttitle}

''First citation with shorttitle.''\footcite[12]{with:shorttitle} 

''Second citation with shorttitle.''\footcite[12]{with:shorttitle} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but i fail to recognize your question, would you be so kind as to clarify it further?

Comment: Can you please add a MWE to play with?

Comment: @egreg : I added an MWE. In making the MWE, I realized that my question concerns **only** cases of abbreviated `shorttitles` that end with a `dot`. I still would like to know if I am the only one who thinks that there should be a comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `\isdot` to the definition of the `citetitle` field format seems to do the trick.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
    [suppbook,suppcollection,suppperiodical]
    {citetitle}{#1\isdot}
```

An alternative solution is to replace the literal period with `\adddot` in the `.bib` file:

```
@book{with:shorttitle,
    author = {Author W. Name},
    year = {2000},
    title = {In Physica},
    shorttitle = {In Phys\adddot},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    }
```

Comment: nice idea. What about adding `\isdot` to the `shorttitle`-field? (e.g., `shorttitle = {In Phys.\isdot}`), instead of changing a global definition? What would you prefer?

Comment: @ClintEastwood I added an alternative solution. Personally, I'd change the `.bib` file in any case; I'd still like an explanation why `\isdot` is absent from some instances of the `citetitle` field format.