# biblatex: stop supressing double punctuation after title which ends with a dot

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, biber

I have a problem with the automatic punctuation while using \footcite:

- I use references whith titles ending with a dot (e.g. 'Die Reichstuerkenhilfe in der Zeit Karls V.'). The dot is part of the title and has to be part of the citation.
- When I cite several titles, the titles are separated by semicolons (;), and when I add some information after a cited title, this is separated from the title by a comma (,).
- My problem is: When I cite a title with a dot in the end, the semicolon or comma is automaticly supressed.

How can I make biblatex showing both, the dot, which ist part of the cited title, and the semicolon or comma, which indicate the end of the title? There has to be a mechanism which prohibits several punctuation signs without space in between.

This is the biblatex part of my document's head:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,
                    style=authortitle-dw,
                    namefont=smallcaps,
                    idembib=false,
                    idemtracker=false,
                    ibidtracker=false,
                    edbyidem=false,
                    edsuper=true,
                    sortlocale=de_DE,
                    url=false, 
                    doi=true,
                    eprint=false]
                    {biblatex}


\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcomma\space } 
\renewcommand*{\nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space } 
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space }
```

Comment: Would it help to write `{V.}` (i.e., with braces around) in the bib entry?

Comment: I think the problem is clear from your description, but it would still be great if you wrote a minimal working example that is ready to compile and that shows the problem. Then problem-solvers have something to copy and edit, which makes it a lot easier to get going with it.

Comment: Need a MWE that replicates the problem. It works with the MWE I setup... see http://i.stack.imgur.com/8q2Rq.png

Comment: An added advantage of using `{V.}`: it will prevent the bibliography style from lowercasing the 'V' when the style is implementing a 'sentence case' style for tiles.

Comment: This problem is similar to [In biblatex, treat periods in journal as abbreviation dots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170547/35864) and [biblatex: why no comma after abbreviated shorttitle?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103061/35864). So you could use `\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1\isdot}` instead. This will treat all dots in `title` fields as abbreviation dots (and not sentence-end periods). If you only want this for one particular entry, better go with `title  = {Die Reichstuerkenhilfe in der Zeit Karls V.\isdot}`.