# Adding a comma after "et al." in citations doesn't work for a different language "et al."

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, babel, languages, biber

In an assignment, I am required to have citations formatted in the following manner:

- in the authoryear style
- with a comma after the andothers-string (normally "et al.")
- with "et al." translated to "ym." (Finnish)

I know how this way to add the comma: `\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}`. Also I know a way to define the bibliography string to be translated into Finnish: `\DefineBibliographyStrings{finnish}{andothers={ym.}}`. Both of these methods work fine separately, but when used simultaneously, *the comma just won't appear*. **How to translate the "et al." and add a comma after it?**

I didn't find a way to do this using Biber. It is my preferred bibliography-handling method, and I wouldn't like to learn a new one just to solve this little problem.

To clarify, below are minimal examples and outputs.

---

```
% Works fine, except that the andothers is in the wrong language:    
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, maxcitenames=1, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

%\DefineBibliographyStrings{finnish}{andothers={ym.}} % To translate "et al."

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{firstinits=true, uniquename=init}

\addbibresource{et_al.bib}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace} % To add the comma

\begin{document}
I refer to~\parencite{reference}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: Exactly what I want, except for the "et al."]

---

```
% The et al. is in the correct language, but the comma ends up missing in the output:    
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, maxcitenames=1, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{finnish}{andothers={ym.}} % To translate "et al."

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{firstinits=true, uniquename=init}

\addbibresource{et_al.bib}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace} % Should add the comma, but somehow doesn't work

\begin{document}
I refer to~\parencite{reference}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: Otherwise fine, but the comma is missing]

---

The .bib file is as follows:

```
@article{reference,
author = {Author, Andrew and Example, Edgar},
title = {Example article},
year = 2015,
journal = {Some Journal}
}
```

Comment: See also [biblatex - How can I force a colon after a period?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200332/35864), [In biblatex, treat periods in journal as abbreviation dots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170547/35864), [biblatex: why no comma after abbreviated shorttitle?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103061/35864).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally, `biblatex` interprets literal periods `.` in bibstrings and the like as sentence-ending periods and suppresses following punctuation to avoid double punctuation.

So we need to make sure `biblatex` knows that the `.` in `ym.` is an abbreviation dot.
This can be done via `ym.\isdot` (where we turn the literal period into a dot afterwards) or `ym\adddot` (where we directly insert an abbreviation dot).

So you could have

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{finnish}{andothers={ym\adddot}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, maxcitenames=1, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{finnish}{andothers={ym\adddot}}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{firstinits=true, uniquename=init}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{reference,
author = {Author, Andrew and Example, Edgar},
title = {Example article},
year = 2015,
journal = {Some Journal}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}

\begin{document}
I refer to~\parencite{reference}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really nice answer! It not only solves the problem but explains how it works too.

Comment: Solved the problem perfectly and elegantly, with explanation of the underlying mechanics. Thanks!